# Form for editing a page doesn't work in Django (CS50 Project)

Tags: python, django, forms, cs50

I am creating a Wikipedia like web app in django and one of the features is that the user is able to edit a page. I have tried to code this, however it doesn't seem to work. I have spent hours trying to figure out the problem and I am unable to fix it. When I enter data into the form, it isn't getting saved onto the file. I press the edit page link, it takes me to editpage.html (which is /wiki/pageName/editpage) and I can type in different data, but when I press the save button, nothing is saved and when I look at the actual file on the disk, it is still the original and none of the edits have been saved.

my views.py editpage function:

```
def editpage(request, title):
if request.method == 'post':
    form = editPageForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        pageTitle = form.cleaned_data['title'].capitalize()
        pageContent = form.cleaned_data['content']
        util.save_entry(pageTitle, pageContent)
        return HttpResponseRedirect(f'/wiki/{pageTitle}')
else:
    return render(request, 'encyclopedia/editpage.html', {
        'title': title,
        'content': util.get_entry(title)
    })
```

my urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.index, name="index"),
    path('<str:title>/editpage', views.editpage, name='editpage'),
    path('newpage', views.newpage, name='newpage'),
    path(f'<str:title>', views.display, name='display')
]
```

the editpage.html website:

```
{% extends "encyclopedia/layout.html" %}

{% block title %}
    Editing: {{ title }} page
{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
    <h1>Editing {{title}}.md</h1>
    <form action='/wiki/{{title}}' method='POST'>
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input type='text' placeholder='Title' name='title' value={{title}}>
        <br>
        <label for='content'>Content (.md format):</label>
        <br>
        <textarea name='content' id='content'>{{content}}</textarea>
        <input type='submit' value='Save'>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

util.save_entry function code:

```
def save_entry(title, content):
"""
Saves an encyclopedia entry, given its title and Markdown
content. If an existing entry with the same title already exists,
it is replaced.
"""
filename = f"entries/{title}.md"
if default_storage.exists(filename):
    default_storage.delete(filename)
default_storage.save(filename, ContentFile(content))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it has to be `request.method == 'POST'`. And I think you should implement the logic with the case `form.is_valid()` return False, too. Go ahead, mate ^^

Comment: What do you mean by 'implement the logic with the case form.is_valid() return False'? Thank you for your help though!

Comment: the is_valid() can return False as well, so I think you should handle that case, too

Comment: I added an else statement that renders the same page but with an error message if the form.is_valid() returned false but when I ran it again, no error message came up so the is_valid() must be true. I still don't know why the edited page isn't saving? Sorry for asking so much questions.